# Reading Oracle data with PyQGIS gives "identifier is not long" error

Tags: pyqgis, oracle-spatial

Do you have any idea how load Oracle spatial data to QGIS with using the PyQGIS? Is it possible? I try:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("*host*", "1521", "*database*", "*username*", "*password*")       
sql = "(SELECT fid, geom FROM target.ms_ft_bh095_v)"
uri.setDataSource("",sql,"GEOM","","fid")
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "test", "oracle")
```

The error message is: ORA-00972: identifier is not long. But FID max value is cca 20 000. Is Oracle driver correct with this syntax? Ms_ft_bh095_v is view in this moment.

Comment: Refer [this][1] answere posted by in stackexchange


  [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131000/loading-oracle-spatial-layers-in-standalone-python-qgis

Answer (score 1):

The actual error message is "ORA-00972: identifier is **too** long". This has nothing to do with the maximum size or value of a column, but rather that an identifier such as a table name or column name is too long (more than 30 characters).

That said, I see nothing wrong with the SELECT statement you use - unless the interface you use adds something to make it invalid. Or your view definition contains something weird. Or your table definition has something weird.

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me.

```
# Import system modules
from xml.dom.minidom import Document
import string
import os
import sys
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtXml import *
from ctypes import*
import cx_Oracle

strProjetName = "C:/OSGeo4W/apache/htdocs/QGIS-Web-Client-master/projects/myworld.qgs"

if os.path.isfile(strProjetName):
   os.remove(strProjetName)

def add_LayersFromDB():
    QGISAPP = QgsApplication(sys.argv, True)     
    QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis", True)
    QgsApplication.initQgis()

    #Connect to Oracle and Fetch Table Names 
    con = cx_Oracle.connect('testinstance/testinstance@189.60.67.146:1521/new')
    print con.version
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(u"select TABLE_NAME from user_tab_columns where data_type='SDO_GEOMETRY'")

    tables = cur.fetchall()

    QgsProject.instance().setFileName(strProjetName)
    print QgsProject.instance().fileName()
    render = QgsMapRenderer()

    uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
    uri.setConnection("189.60.67.146", "1521", "new", "testinstance", "testinstance")

    render = QgsMapRenderer()

    for t in tables :
       print str(t[0])

       uri.setDataSource('',  str(t[0]), "GEOMETRY")
       uri.uri()
       vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(),str(t[0]), 'oracle')
       QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
       lst = [ vlayer.id() ]
       render.setLayerSet(lst)
       rect = QgsRectangle(render.fullExtent())            
       rect.scale(1.1)
       render.setExtent(rect)

    QgsProject.instance().write()

    cur.close()
    con.close()

    QgsApplication.exitQgis()


add_LayersFromDB()
```